# calling a jquery function from a button which inside the function itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Here is the code to call webservice to return json

```
$('#page_job_list_pages').live('pageshow',function(){

      try {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://domain.com/json/" + encodeURIComponent(tid),
          type: 'get',
          dataType: 'json',
          error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('page_job_list_pages - failed to retrieve pages');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
          },
          success: function (data) {
            $("#page_job_list_pages_list").html("");
            $.each(data.nodes,function (node_index,node_value) {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(node_value));
              if(node_index != 0) {
                  var companyName = node_value.node.field_basic_info.match("Company:(.*)date");
                  $("#page_job_list_pages_list").append($("<li></li>",{"html":"<a href='#node_view' id='" + node_value.node.Nid + "' class='page_job_list_pages_list_title'>" + companyName[1] + "</a>"}));
              }
            });
            $("#page_job_list_pages_list").listview("destroy").listview();
            $("#page_job_list_pages_list").append('<a onclick="()" data-role="button" data-theme="a">TEST</a>');
          }
        });
      }
      catch (error) { alert("page_job_list_pages_list - " + error); }
    });


this line is a button

    $("#page_job_list_pages_list").append('<a onclick="()" data-role="button" data-theme="a">TEST</a>');
```

i want to call the jquery function to query the json again.

HOW to do that?

Comment: You want it to do what now? I'm not sure your question is as descriptive as needed. You want to run the the method again after it was run on `pageshow`?

Comment: run it again after clicked a button

Comment: See code I've added below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've wrapped your query in a function. I am assuming this is what you want. I've also added the call in the click handlers of your buttons to query again.

Note:
As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live(). (Source: http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$('#page_job_list_pages').live('pageshow',function(){
  queryJSON();
});

function queryJSON(){
  try {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://domain.com/json/" + encodeURIComponent(tid),
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('page_job_list_pages - failed to retrieve pages');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
      },
      success: function (data) {
        $("#page_job_list_pages_list").html("");
        $.each(data.nodes,function (node_index,node_value) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(node_value));
          if(node_index != 0) {
              var companyName = node_value.node.field_basic_info.match("Company:(.*)date");
              $("#page_job_list_pages_list").append($("<li></li>",{"html":"<a href='#node_view' id='" + node_value.node.Nid + "' class='page_job_list_pages_list_title'>" + companyName[1] + "</a>"}));
          }
        });
        $("#page_job_list_pages_list").listview("destroy").listview();
        $("#page_job_list_pages_list").append('<a onclick="queryJSON();" data-role="button" data-theme="a">TEST</a>');
      }
    });
  }
  catch (error) { alert("page_job_list_pages_list - " + error); }
}
this line is a button

$("#page_job_list_pages_list").append('<a onclick="queryJSON();" data-role="button" data-theme="a">TEST</a>');
```